# Multisignature - get one signed transaction, send another, use first signed transaction

Tags: multisig

The nature of my problem is the following: I, side A, need to get a multisig transaction signed by side B to send it to side C later on, store that signed transaction (not broadcast it yet), then sign another transaction by me (side A) for side B, broadcast it and finally use my first signed transaction I got first to send it to side C.

Is it possible? I've read that every time new transaction is being signed there is a sync required for key image.

Question is: Does it make my scenario impossible to do? 
I hope it doesn't...

Comment: Explain in detail what you want. And in particular, which wallets in there are multisig between which parties.

Comment: Side A and B are on multisig and side C has a regullar address. The need is to store one transaction, do others and then use the stored one later on without need to sync again what requires kind of permission from side B. Side B must send back data to sync - what if it doesnt want to?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming those two transactions do not double spend each other, it's perfectly acceptable. If the second transaction double spends the first one (which hasn't been mined yet), then the first one will be rejected if it's broadcast to the network.

You can't sign twice with the same multisig data, but that does not prevent a signed transaction from being held for a while before being broadcast.

Comment: So key image is not based on balance but is randomly generated then I guess(?). Pay attention I broadcast another transactions with new key images while key image for the first is not updated.

Comment: The key image is not random, nor based on balance. They key image will always be the same when you spend a given output.

Comment: Output or input? If it's based on output then what is the obstacle? Doing transactions in sync order is very limitating... seems like I will have to look in btc's direction... too bad. I want to do my project with XMR

Comment: An inout to a tx is an output from another. I do not understand your point about sync order.

Comment: OK. Simply words - can I sign transaction before I put any funds on the multisig wallet? The point is to secure sides from locking in funds on multisig 2/2. To do it 2 of 2 parties must have signed payout tx's from that multisig address (the amounts they will pay in). Please don't ask for the reason just deliver the answer.

Comment: To sign a transaction spending money from an account (multisig is not), you must know the output you are spending. So, in short, no, you can't sign a spend from a wallet before sending the money to that wallet.